# Can't set display:none to iFrame, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to create function which fades in a div and an iframe on click. The iframe is nested in the div. It works. Unfortunately when I want to make them both fade out it doesn't work. The div fades out having `display:none` property on it and iframe stays `display:inline` despite jQuery initiating fade out command. Could someone help me to sort it out, please?

My HTML:

```
<div id="icontent">
    <div id="frame">
        <input type="button" id="hide" value=""/>
        <iframe src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.gallery').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).prop('href');
     $("#icontent").fadeIn(200).width($(window).width());
    $("#mainFrame").attr("src", link).load(function(){ 
                $("#mainFrame").contents().find('body').css("background-image", "none").css("background-color", "transparent");
                $("#mainFrame").fadeIn(300);
            }) 

});
$("#hide").click(function () {
    $("#icontent").fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#mainFrame").attr("src", "about:blank").fadeOut(10);
    }, 250);
});
$("#icontent").click(function () {
    $("#icontent").fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#mainFrame").attr("src", "about:blank").fadeOut(10);
    }, 250);
});
$(document).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
    $("#icontent").fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#mainFrame").attr("src", "about:blank").fadeOut(10);
    }, 250);
    }
});
});
```

My CSS:

```
#frame{width:53.125em;margin:3.125em auto;position:relative;}
#mainFrame{width:53.125em;height:40.625em;overflow:hidden;background:none transparent;display:none;}
#icontent{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:transparent url(images/tlogaleria.jpg);background-size:cover;text-align:center;display:none;z-index:10000;}
#loader{position:absolute;top:60%;left:20%;padding:0.375em;height:1em;width:1em;background:white url(images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat 50%;display:none;border-radius:1.563em;opacity:0.8;z-index:100;}
#hide{top:-1.438em;right:1.563em;position:absolute;width:1.25em;height:1.25em;border:0 none;padding:0;margin:0;}
.svg #hide{background:transparent url(images/close.svg) no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%;}
.no-svg #hide{background:transparent url(images/fallback/close.png) no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%;}
#hide:hover{opacity:0.5;}
#hide:hover{cursor:pointer;}
```

You can see it working [here](http://www.positive-space.pl/projekty/), by cklicking on the first carousel item on the left (the one with EF-2000 image ;))

Thanks in advance for all hints, cheers, Dan.

Comment: Is  it supposed to look like **[this](http://i.imgur.com/LSEo3Gk.png)**?

Comment: Is this is how it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/67rrj5mo/ ?

Comment: The first time I klick the link iframe fades in smoothly changing from display:none to display:inline, when I click 'x' or press esc div wrapping iframe fades out but I want iframe change from display:inline to display:none as well. Otherwise iframe doesn't fade in smoothly when I klick the link the second time. It needs to be display:none tofade in smoothly.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity actually your example works exactly the same way my example works. Look at the iframe when you click 'x' or press esc, div .icontent fades out and ends up with display:none, and that's correct, and iframe is still display:inline and I want it display:none as well.

Comment: @zer00ne no, that's not about how it looks, that's about why is the iframe not changing to display:none from display:inline after closing it. Check developers tools in your browser to see what I mean.
PS: fadeOut should change status to display:none but it fails somehow.

Comment: my example is your code I haven't done anything except adding `display:none` to the `#icontent`, why do you want to make `display:none` to the iframe while it is already disappeared?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Ok, I'll explain that step by step: THAT'S STEP1:
1. click the link, 2. wrapper div (.icontent in my case) fades in smoothly for 0.2 sec changing status from display:none to display:block, 3. iframe fades in smoothly for 0.3 sec after all the iframe's content is being loaded up, 4. everything is being loaded up perfectly, SUCCESS!!

Comment: @Mi-Creativity STEP 2: 1. click closing button or press ESC, 2. wrapper div (.icontent) fades out smoothly for 0.2 sec changing status from display:block to display:none, 3. iframe is not changing status from display:inline to display:none despite having fadeOut(10) command in jQuery function!! 4. everything is not being visible anymore, which is good, but wait until step 3

Comment: @Mi-Creativity STEP 3: 1. I want to see the same iframe with gallery again without refreshing the page, 2. klick on link again 3. wrapper div shows up properly but then iframe doesn't fade in, it can't fade in smoothly because it didn't change its status from display:inline to display:none in step 2! It shows up straight away instead of nice smooth animation of fadeIn. FAIL!! I hope I cleared everything up for you now :)

Comment: Try this now https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/67rrj5mo/1/ and check whether this can fix it for you.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity no, sorry. I actually tried to set attr, just like you did and I also tried to set css via jQuery, no change:( See it in browser's developers tools, it looks like it changes to display:none for a small part of a second but goes back to display:inline for some reason. That's strange...

Comment: Actually I tried with to `.removeAttr()` , `.addClass()` , `.css()` , and `.attr("style", "")` but all didn't work, the `style="display:inline"` is add automatically and override other ways, however this `.attr("style", "display:none");` was the *only* way I could change the `style="display:inline"` part into `style` only.so I thought it might work you.

Comment: Since this didn't work too then I'm apologize I'm not sure what else would work for you, but maybe attaching more than one `iframe` and hide/show them with javascript

Comment: @Mi-Creativity that's not a problem, thank you for your time!! :)

Comment: @Daniel, check this, and hopefully it'll work for you https://jsfiddle.net/67rrj5mo/3/

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Thank you, but I think I've found simpler solution! I've added `$("#mainFrame").css({"display":"none"});` right before .icontent fades in and it seems to work, I've also deleted all fade outs for the iframe. But I still dn't know why iframe doesn't want to fade out as it was in initial function, so much to learn about jQuery!! Again thank you for your time!